# S_ISDIR thinks file is a directory

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to print all the files' and folders' names inside a directory and its subdirectories.
The problem is that files are also considered directories? Sorry for posting my whole code, but I really don't have any idea why this is happening. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

void parcurgere(char path[1000]){

    char aux[1000];
    strcpy(aux, path);

    struct dirent *ent;
    DIR *d = opendir(path);

    while((ent = readdir(d))){

        struct stat my_stat;

        stat(path, &my_stat);
        if(S_ISDIR(my_stat.st_mode) && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")!=0 && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")!=0 && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".DS_Store")!=0){
            printf("%s - folder\n", ent->d_name);
            char x[1000];
            strcpy(x, path);
            strcat(x, "/");
            strcat(x, ent->d_name);
            parcurgere(x);
        }
        if(S_ISREG(my_stat.st_mode)){
            printf("%s - fisier\n", ent->d_name);
        }

        strcpy(path, aux);
        //path[strlen(path) - poz] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(){

    char path[1000];
    strcpy(path, ".");

    parcurgere(path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz I did that. It's in the first if.

Comment: @RadLexus Do you mean my folder structure/tree?

Comment: If you ste through your code with a debugger you should be able to find this issue quickly. I don't have a linux here so I cannot check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `stat()` on the directory you opened with `opendir()`:

```
DIR *d = opendir(path);

while((ent = readdir(d))){

    struct stat my_stat;

    stat(path, &my_stat);
```

So yes, the contents of `my_stat` indicate that it's a directory - because `path` is a directory.

You're also not checking the return code from `stat()`.  That can fail, and if you do change `path` to `stat()` the entry returned from `readdir()`, you will get incorrect results if `stat()` fails.

Comment: And to correct this, you'd have to make a string out of `path` + / + `ent->d_name` and pass that to `stat()` - i.e. move the code that populates the `x` array up, and do `stat(x, &my_stat);`

Comment: @nos Indeed.  In fact, I somehow had originally read the posted code as calling `stat(ent->d_name, &my_stat);`, hence my deleted answer...